# Whitelisting ec2 instances in a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have a `server A` in which I am only allowing requests from a set of IP's which are whitelisted. I want to send requests from ec2 instances in a particular VPC to the server A. Currently, each time when I create a new instance in the VPC I  whitelist the public IP so I can send the request. (or attach static IP and whitelist it). Is there any other way to handle this so that each time I don't have to whitelist it

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirements? Are you saying that traffic will go from Amazon EC2 instances in `VPC-A` to `Server-A` that is in `VPC-B`? Are the VPCs connected via VPC Peering, or does the communication go via Public IP addresses by exiting `VPC-A` and then entering `VPC-B`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you would place instances in a private subnet and use [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) to connect to the internet. The reason is that NAT gateway has **static public IP**. Thus, all your instances would use that IP and you just need to whitelist the single IP, regardless of how many instances you have.